# xcode swift: how to display a website as pop-over

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I am working on an app with links to external websites. I have been using code that opens safari separately, but I would like code that opens the website as a pop-over. Is this an option?

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://www.bing.com")!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a UIWebView and load the url into it, you can add that to an existing view or create a view controller with a web view in it and present it as a popover.

```
    let aWebView = UIWebView()

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)

    aWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

    self.view.addSubview(aWebView)
```

Comment: +1 as this helped to reach a new solution post iOS 12.0, to use WKWebView.
Also "loadRequest" is deprecated now.